# Taking .mp3 with ajax froma directory

Tags: javascript, ajax, audio-player

I have this code from a mp3 music player, but I can't take the songs from a directory instead of the page's url

```
var songs = [{
    {
    title: 'Blackout City',
    artist: 'Anamanaguchi',
    url: 'http://foo.com/365/files/foo.mp3',
    art: 'http://foo.com/365/files/foo.jpg'
    },
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  This is just (part of) an object in JavaScript, this code doesn't actually *do* anything.  What are you trying to *do* and in what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it from the filepath (*I assume that's what you mean*) because javascript doesn't have access to the user's filesystem (*assuming you meant from a filepath on the user's computer*) for security purposes, and of course it can't get it from the server's filepath because js runs on the user's computer (*i assume, because node wasn't tagged*).

sorry, you will have to use a url.

ps: please be more specific with future questions so people don't have to *assume* so much..

Comment: thank you so much... and sorry it's my first question... I'm a bit noob :),

Comment: I mean the server filepath.... how can I get mp3 files for my music player from a folder in the server filepath???